# Memory leak in recursive IO function - PAP

Tags: haskell, recursion, memory-leaks, profiling

I've written a library called [amqp-worker](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amqp-worker) that provides a function called `worker` that polls a message queue (like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)) for messages, calling a handler when a message is found. Then it goes back to polling.

It's leaking memory. I've profiled it and the graph says `PAP` (partial function application) is the culprit. **Where is the leak in my code? How can I avoid leaks when looping in `IO` with `forever`?**

[image]

Here are some relevant functions. [The full source is here](https://github.com/seanhess/amqp-worker).

[Example Program](https://github.com/seanhess/amqp-worker/blob/master/test/Example.hs). This leaks

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- connect
  conn <- Worker.connect (fromURI "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672")

  -- initialize the queues
  Worker.initQueue conn queue
  Worker.initQueue conn results

  -- publish a message
  Worker.publish conn queue (TestMessage "hello world")

  -- create a worker, the program loops here
  Worker.worker def conn queue onError (onMessage conn)
```

[worker](https://github.com/seanhess/amqp-worker/blob/master/src/Network/AMQP/Worker/Worker.hs#L35)

```
worker :: (FromJSON a, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadCatch m) => WorkerOptions -> Connection -> Queue key a -> (WorkerException SomeException -> m ()) -> (Message a -> m ()) -> m ()
worker opts conn queue onError action =
  forever $ do
    eres <- consumeNext (pollDelay opts) conn queue
    case eres of
      Error (ParseError reason bd) ->
        onError (MessageParseError bd reason)

      Parsed msg ->
        catch
          (action msg)
          (onError . OtherException (body msg))
    liftBase $ threadDelay (loopDelay opts)
```

[consumeNext](https://github.com/seanhess/amqp-worker/blob/master/src/Network/AMQP/Worker/Message.hs#L100)

```
consumeNext :: (FromJSON msg, MonadBaseControl IO m) => Microseconds -> Connection -> Queue key msg -> m (ConsumeResult msg)
consumeNext pd conn queue =
    poll pd $ consume conn queue
```

[poll](https://github.com/seanhess/amqp-worker/blob/master/src/Network/AMQP/Worker/Poll.hs#L9)

```
poll :: (MonadBaseControl IO m) => Int -> m (Maybe a) -> m a
poll us action = do
    ma <- action
    case ma of
      Just a -> return a
      Nothing -> do
        liftBase $ threadDelay us
        poll us action
```

Comment: What's your ghc version and how are you compiling?

Comment: It's set to lts-7.3 so that's GHC 8.0.1. I'm compiling with stack install --profile. But I get the memory leak with a normal stack install. Using the default ghc options from the stack template:  -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N

Comment: This example is very far from minimal - you are importing your entire library (`Network.AMQP.Worker`) in your example program. As it stands, this is far too broad.

Comment: I was thinking there might be something obvious. So you're suggesting I reduce it to a minimal example?

Comment: This is my first time hunting down a memory leak. I am wondering if there's a good way to figure out where they are in a program like this

Comment: I would try getting rid of the monad type classes and just using `IO`. I'm not sure if it is likely to be the problem but it would be nice to have one fewer thing to worry about.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that demonstrates your problem:

```
main :: IO ()
main = worker

{-# NOINLINE worker #-}
worker :: (Monad m) => m ()
worker =
  let loop = poll >> loop
  in loop

poll :: (Monad m) => m a
poll = return () >> poll
```

If you remove the `NOINLINE`, or specialize `m` to
`IO` (while compiling with `-O`), the leak goes away.

I wrote a detailed [blog
post](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-01-10-nested-loop-space-leak) about why
exactly this code leaks memory. The quick summary is, as Reid points out in his
answer, that the code creates and remembers a chain of partial applications of
`>>`s.

I also filed a [ghc ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13080) about this.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an easier example to understand is this one

```
main :: IO ()
main = let c = count 0
       in c >> c

{-# NOINLINE count #-}
count :: Monad m => Int -> m ()
count 1000000 = return ()
count n = return () >> count (n+1)
```

Evaluating `f >> g` for IO actions yields some kind of closure that has references to both `f` and `g` (it's basically the composition of `f` and `g` as functions on state tokens). `count 0` returns a thunk `c` that will evaluate to a big structure of closures of the form `return () >> return () >> return () >> ...`. When we execute `c` we build up this structure, and since we have to execute `c` a second time the whole structure is still live. So this program leaks memory (regardless of optimization flags).

When `count` is specialized to `IO` and optimizations are enabled, GHC has a variety of tricks available to avoid building up this data structure; but they all rely on knowing that the monad is `IO`.

Returning to the original `count :: Monad m => Int -> m ()`, we can try to avoid building this big structure by changing the last line to

```
count n = return () >>= (\_ -> count (n+1))
```

Now the recursive call is hidden inside a lambda, so `c` is just a small structure `return () >>= (\_ -> BODY)`. This does actually avoid the space leak when compiling without optimizations. However when optimizations are enabled, GHC floats out `count (n+1)` from the body of the lambda (since it doesn't depend on the argument) producing

```
count n = return () >>= (let body = count (n+1) in \_ -> body)
```

and now `c` is a large structure again...

Comment: How does the use of `NOINLINE` make the program comparable to the original leaky one?

Comment: GHC not inlining or specializing is the generic case (when the function is defined in a different module, not small, etc.) GHC knows many tricks, and when you minimize these tricks may kick in. Using `NOINLINE` stops many of these tricks lets you minimize further.

Answer (score 3):

The memory leak was in `poll`. Using [`monad-loops`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html), I changed the definition to the following: It looks like `untilJust` does the same thing as my recursion, but fixes the leak.

Can anyone comment as to why my previous definition of `poll` was leaking memory?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Network.AMQP.Worker.Poll where

import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control (MonadBaseControl)
import Control.Monad.Base (liftBase)
import Control.Monad.Loops (untilJust)

poll :: (MonadBaseControl IO m) => Int -> m (Maybe a) -> m a
poll us action = untilJust $ do
    ma <- action
    case ma of
      Just a -> return $ Just a
      Nothing -> do
        liftBase $ threadDelay us
        return Nothing
```